# Access to the data of a nested private class

Tags: c++, tree, nested, getter

I have a Tree class which has a Node nested class as private.
In my Tree class, I have a public method that sets a Tree into my Node's children. The problem is that I have errors when I want to access the `_children` member of my Node class even though I am using a getter.
The method in question is `ins(unsigned short i, Tree* childTree)`.
Here is my code.
**tree.hpp**

```
#ifndef TREE_HPP
#define TREE_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef> 
// #include "node.hpp"

template <typename T, unsigned short N>
class Tree {
private:

  class Node {
    private:
      T _data;
      Tree* _children[N];
    public:
      Node();
      Node(T);
      Tree** getChildren() {return this->_children;}
      T getData(){return this->_data;}
      ~Node() = default;
  };

  Node* _info;
public:
  Tree();
  Tree(T, unsigned short);
  Tree(const Tree&) = delete;  // copy constructor
  Tree& operator= (const Tree&) = delete; // assignement by copy constructor
  Tree (Tree&&); // transfer constructor
  Tree& operator= (Tree&&); // assignement by transfer constructor
  ~Tree() {delete _info;}
  // ~Tree() = default;
  bool ins(unsigned short i, Tree childTree) {
    if (_info){
      // _info->getChildren()[i] = std::move(childTree);
      _info->getChildren()[i] = &childTree;
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
};

template <typename T, unsigned short N> // Node class default constructor
Tree<T,N>::Node::Node(){
  _data = 0;
  _children = nullptr;
}

template <typename T, unsigned short N> // Node class constructor
Tree<T,N>::Node::Node(T data){
  _data = data;
  for (unsigned short i = 0; i < N; i++) 
    _children[i] = NULL;
}

template <typename T, unsigned short N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree() 
  : _info(nullptr) {}

template <typename T, unsigned short N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree(T data, unsigned short size) {
  Node* node = new Node(data);
  _info = node;
}

template <typename T, unsigned short N>
Tree<T, N>::Tree(Tree&& t) {
  _info = t._info;
  t._info = nullptr;
}

template <typename T, unsigned short N>
Tree<T, N>& Tree<T, N>::operator= (Tree&& t) {
  if (&t != this) {delete _info; _info = t._info; t._info = nullptr;}
  return *this;
}

#endif
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <exception>
#include "tree.hpp"

#define SIZE 5
int main() {
  Tree<char,SIZE> n1('A',SIZE);
  n1.ins(0,Tree<char,SIZE>('B',SIZE));
  n1.ins(1,Tree<char,SIZE>('C',SIZE));
  return 0;
}
```

Also I should say that the `_children` has to be the type of Tree and not Node.
Thank you in advanced

Comment: Please edit your question to include the errors you are getting. The error I get when compiling with g++ is quite clear, `Node` is not a base class of `Tree`. Therefore, `this->Node::` is not valid. Do you mean `this->_info` ?

Comment: @ChrisMM I edited the question. I do mean ```this->_info```.  I think there is something wrong with my getter method in Node class. I want to get the `_children` and modify the i-th index and set it to a new Tree instance.

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/9rNi-0 Works for me. With both g++ and MSVC. The exact error you are getting may help.

Comment: @ChrisMM Sorry again to bother you. I edited my code again and now there is not any error but i would like to know if what I do is correct or not and see if the children that I am setting are really being placed in the good place or not?

Comment: `_info->getChildren()[i] = &childTree;` You are assigning the node a temporary `Tree` object. This will lead to undefined behaviour. If you want to know if it is doing what it is supposed to, you will need to print out some values to check, or use a debugger to step through. Also, the function `info` and `fils` return `Node` pointers, but `Node` is a private class...

Comment: @ChrisMM but what if instead of assigning i use `std::move(&childTree)`

Comment: Then you are moving a pointer to a temporary object, same problem. You either want to store the object itself (i.e., not a pointer), or create a new `Tree` object using `new` which is a copy of the `childTree`, i.e. `new Tree( std::move(childTree) );`

Comment: @ChrisMM so is there a way to do it in a way that doesn't copy the object and pass a pointer to an object?

Comment: @ChrisMM I have to disable the copy function and it is because of that that I have this problem. If no I could have do ```Tree<char,SIZE> treechild('B',SIZE)``` and then I could have do ```n1.ins(0,&treechild```|

Comment: The 'copy' I showed isn't really a copy, it is a move using your move constructor.

Comment: @ChrisMM but if I do ```n1.ins(0, new Tree<char, SIZE>('B', SIZE))``` I would have a memory leak. How can I do a `delete` if I do something like this?

Comment: I would suggest keeping the `new` out of `main` and keep it in the `Tree` class, if that's the solution you intend to use. On removal of the object from the tree, then you would free it, including in the destructor.

Comment: @ChrisMM Thank you. I am going to do that.